# Why do we step by "n + n" in a bottom-up Merge sort?

Tags: java, mergesort

In a bottom-up merge sort for the inner loop, why is there a need for:   i+= n + n?   Won't i += n work just fine?

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/MergeBU.java.html

```
 public static void sort(Comparable[] a) {
        int N = a.length;
        Comparable[] aux = new Comparable[N];
        for (int n = 1; n < N; n = n+n) {
            for (int i = 0; i < N-n; i += n+n) {
                int lo = i;
                int m  = i+n-1;
                int hi = Math.min(i+n+n-1, N-1);
                merge(a, aux, lo, m, hi);
            }
        }
        assert isSorted(a);
    }
```

Comment: Does `i += 2*n` make more sense?

Comment: I don't understand how somebody can vote to close this question for *why this code isn't working* since the code compiles and works as expected. The question is about explanation of the code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: That was me.  If the OP *had* tried it (and he/she really *should* have tried it before posting), the code wouldn't have worked.  Thus I view this question as equivalent to "I tried changing X to Y, and it didn't work.  Why not?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mergesort merges sorted subarrays of length `n = 1, 2, 4, ..., N/2` in the `1st, 2nd, 3rd, ..., (lg(N))th` iteration of the outer loop. Since **2** corresponding subarrays are merged, the index has to be increased by `2*n = 2, 4, 8, ..., N` to skip the indices of **both** subarrays that were just merged.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom-up merge sort is a non-recursive variant of the merge sort, in which the array is sorted by a sequence of passes. During each pass, the array is divided into blocks of size m (Initially, m=1,). Every two adjacent blocks are merged (as in normal merge sort), and the next pass is made with a twice larger value of m, effectively merging our previously sorted (smaller) blocks together.

Ref:

http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Merge_sort

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop steps through the numbers 1,2,4,8,16, ect. The inner loop merge-sorts all pairs of subarrays of size, 1,2,4,8, ect.

After it has sorted the a pair of subarrays of size n, the next pair starts at n (size of sub array  one) + n (size of subarray two) + i (the start of the current pair of subarrays).